# On redirecting between pages data not loaded completly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

When i try to move to home page from any other page, the data does not load fully. text is loaded, but images are not loaded. ps:The site is static.

when redirect from any other pages to home page the data must load completely including images.
but here images are not loaded. But once i reload page, it works correctly.
Iam using Nuxt 3 with Vite as Bundler

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.